# Get larger facebook image through firebase login

Tags: swift, facebook-graph-api, firebase, facebook-login, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase to login a user through facebook. This all works fine and I can get the users FB profile image, although it is to small. Can somebody tell me how to get a larger one, the code I am using:

```
     override func viewDidLoad() {
            let loginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
            loginButton.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email"]
            loginButton.delegate = self
            self.view.addSubview(loginButton) 
        }

func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError?) {

        let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credentialWithAccessToken(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString)

            FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithCredential(credential) { (user, error) in
                if let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser {
                for profile in user.providerData {
                let photoUrl = profile.photoURL?.absoluteString //SMALL IMAGE
                   }
                }
            }
        }
```

(This is done in swift)

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem? Can you post the solution? Thanks

Comment: Yes I will get back to you later as I can not remember I will need to check the code.

Comment: If you found a solution, post it here

Comment: @HenryBrown did you check the code? Sorry but I'm a bit stuck with this and I couldn't find a solution yet :)

Comment: Sorry I have taken so long. I have been busy. I have marked the correct answer below. I have used: let photoUrl = profile.photoURL?.absoluteString + "?type=large" this works for me

Answer (score -2, accepted):

According to the Facebook [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/) on Profile Picture, you should be able to specify the size by appending `width` and `height` to the url:

```
let photoUrl = profile.photoURL?.absoluteString + "?width=\(width)&height=\(height)"
```

or by specifying the type:

```
let photoUrl = profile.photoURL?.absoluteString + "?type=large"
```

Comment: This is correct if you want to retrieve a picture with facebook API, but he is asking to do it through firebase and if you attach + "?type=large" or + "?width=\(width)&height=\(height)", the page is empty (no picture)

Answer (score 2):

Once the FB user authenticates, make a `FBSDKGraphRequest` using `FBSDKGraphRequestConnection` to get the users FBid, using which you can get the users profile picture by pluggin the id here:

https://graph.facebook.com//picture?type=large&return_ssl_resources=1

instead of `type=large` you can use `?width=<width>&height=<height>` too

too

Answer (score 1):

Once you get the photo Url, just add `"?width=400&height=400"` to the photo url. Here, height=width=400, you can choose your own height and width. It surely works!

Comment: Doesn't work. That only works for the facebook graph API. It doesn't work with Firebase auth.