# Can't get FB profile picture with Firebase

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

I cannot get user's Facebook profile picture into my imageView. I am trying to get with Picasso library. Have an idea to solve that? Here is my codes. Thanks in advance!

R.string.facebook_provider_id= "facebook.com"

Error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.yunus.ototakip, PID: 3045 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity

ComponentInfo{com.example.yunus.ototakip/com.example.yunus.ototakip.Hesabim}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null.
```

**Hesabim.java**

```
public class Hesabim extends AppCompatActivity {

public FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
public FirebaseUser user;
public CircleImageView userImage;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hesabim);
    userImage= (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.kullaniciHesapResmi);
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()==null)
    {
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(this,Giris.class));
    }

    kullaniciMail.setText(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail());
    String facebookUserId = "";
    user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    for(UserInfo profile : user.getProviderData()) {
        // check if the provider id matches "facebook.com"
        if(profile.getProviderId().equals(getString(R.string.facebook_provider_id))) {
            facebookUserId = profile.getUid();
        }
    }
    String photoUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + facebookUserId + "/picture?type=medium";
    Picasso.with(this).load(photoUrl).into(userImage);
```

**hesabim.xml**

```
        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/kullaniciHesapResmi"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/kullanici_pp"
            fancy:civ_border_color="@color/colorAccent"
            fancy:civ_border_width="2dp" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i hope you are asking permission for profile picture from facebook first, bcz without permission facebook will not allow you to get anything.

```
loginButton.setReadPermissions("public_profile", "email", "user_friends", "user_education_history", "user_hometown", "user_likes", "user_work_history");
```

or you can also use facebook callback to get user profile image, like this..

```
private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> mCallBack = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(final LoginResult loginResult) {

            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(
                                JSONObject object,
                                GraphResponse response) {
                            Log.e("response: ", response + "");
                            try {
                                String id = object.getString("id").toString();
                                String email = object.getString("email").toString();
                                String name = object.getString("name").toString();
                                String profilePicUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId() + "/picture?type=large";
                                Log.d("imageFB", profilePicUrl);
                                Log.d("FB_ID:", id);


                                checkFBLogin(id, email, name, profilePicUrl);

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            finish();
                        }

                    });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender,birthday,friends,likes,hometown,education,work");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
        }
```

Comment: My code is including loginButton.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile"); line.

Comment: Should I use your code in my LoginActivity or activity that opening after LoginActivity?

Comment: Use this code in login activity. And pass image to next activity.

Comment: Yes.. its mine.. using this function i m passing fb data to server.

Comment: My code was working without this but now I'm getting an issue when I try to get Facebook's profile picture like this one: https://lookaside.facebook.com/platform/profilepic/?asid=413359148997919&height=100&width=100

Answer (score 2):

You can get the profile picture in good resolution with this much simple solution:

If you followed the Firebase samples, inside updateUI method use:

```
photoUrl = user.getPhotoUrl(); //here you get the picture

photoUrlstr = photoUrl.toString(); //here you store the link to quality

photoUrlstr = photoUrlstr + "?height=500"; //adjust quality

Glide.with(this).load(photoUrlstr).into(IVperfil); //put it in Imageview
```

Hope it helps, as this is too much simple code.