# Get larger Facebook image through Firebase login (swift)

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, facebook-login, firebase-authentication

I'm doing a login with Facebook through the Firebase login.
I do:

```
FBSDKLoginManager().logIn(withReadPermissions: [...], from: self) { (result, error) in 

       guard let current = FBSDKAccessToken.current() else { return }
       guard let token = current.tokenString else { return }           
       let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: token)
       FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in
            //user.photoURL
       }
}
```

`user.photoURL` contains the url of the image, but it is very small (100x100), I would like to retrieve the bigger image.

[On this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38032124/get-larger-facebook-image-through-firebase-login) they say to add `?type=large` to the url but it doesn't work.

Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go through Facebook Graph then you can get the larger image from url

Here is an example of that, in this url you just need to pass your id, you will get larger image

> http://graph.facebook.com/yourId/picture?width=400&height=400

For more info you can check this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/user/picture)